# How do I change the color and thickness of multiple curves?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to graph the following:

```
Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}]
```

while making the two curves thicker. I have tried doing

```
Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Thick}] 

Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Thickness[.1]}] 

Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.1],Black, Blue}]
```

All to no avail. In fact, the latter actually changes the colors slightly for some reason. So any help on how to change the color and make them thicker would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html).  `Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], 
   Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}]`

Comment: Or you can use lists: `Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({#, Thickness[0.01]} & /@ {Black, Blue})]`

Comment: Thanks @AnjanKumar! That did the trick perfectly!

Comment: @BobHanlon Yours also works very well, and more compact. Thanks!

Comment: or `Plot[{E^x, x}, {x, -1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.1], Black}, {Thickness[.1], Blue}}]`

Comment: I think the linked topic answers your question, let me know if you disagree.